# Method level transaction timeout setting in CDI

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, transactions, cdi

There is a **org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional** annotation in Spring using which we can give method level timeout for transactions.

I am trying to achieve the same thing using CDI. But the J2EE equivalent annotation **javax.transaction.Transactional** does not have an option to configure timeout.

I have searched for some time but couldn't find much till now. Is it possible to have method level transaction timeout in CDI ? If not then any other way to achieve it ?

```
//@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, timeout=5_MIN, rollbackFor = {OHException.class })
@Transactional( value= TxType.REQUIRES_NEW,rollbackOn= {OHException.class})
public <T> T saveDomainObject(T object) throws OHException{
.....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible with JTA and its `javax.transaction.Transactional` annotation.
Usually you are only able to set transaction timeout **globally**, for all methods.

But other ways, which I'm aware of, to achieve something similar:

- If you are using JBoss/ WildFly then you can use its specific annotation: `@org.jboss.annotation.ejb.TransactionTimeout`, which is exactly what you are looking for.
- You can configure timeout for a specific query with *query hints*. For example since JPA 2.0 there is a `javax.persistence.query.timeout` hint - its usage looks like `query.setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 3000);`.

But still, in most cases the easiest solution is to increase timeout for all transactions.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using weblogic server. I'll try the query hints and update the results..

Comment: org.jboss.annotation.ejb.TransactionTimeout only works on EJBs that use container managed transactions. I am not sure if CDI's @Transactional fits that bill, as CDI uses the User Transaction API which is afaik Bean managed. So is this answer really correct?